# Exception parsing json data

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

[image]I am storing json data into cookie and getting from the cookie.

I am adding data into a json object

```
x[grapObj.toString()]=graphic;
```

I am taking the first value for timebeing as x[0] which gives the previous one. The *graphics* will contain collection of several objects.
Storing into cookie

```
$.cookie('Grap0',JSON.stringify(x[0]),1);
```

Getting data from cookie

```
var json123=$.cookie('Grap0');
```

When this is done object is seen as [object object]
Now i try to parse but it throwing exception

Parsing the json

```
var obj12 = JSON.parse(json123);
var obj12 = $.parseJSON(json123);
```

I tried both the ways but nothing worked

Comment: What gives `console.log(JSON.stringify(x[0]))`?

Comment: What is the value of `x[0]`?

Comment: what's the content of "json123" ? Hide every sensiive content

Comment: Please provide the definition of x so that we can reproduce.

Comment: `x[grapObj.toString()]=graphic;`, if `grapObj.toString()` is not `0`, you should not expect `x[0]` to be your `graphic` object.

Comment: @plalx 0 is the index value i am taking the value added

Comment: @Jagadesh, what is the result of `grapObj.toString()`?

Comment: @plalx **Grap0** is a the result

Answer (score 1):

Cookies store stuff in strings. If the plugin returned `json123` is an `[object Object]`, then it could have already been parsed! You might have [forgot about setting it to do so](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#json).

Comment: Double parsing was me guess as well +1

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer Above is my code pls suggest where i am missing

Comment: i am seeing [object object] in the debug mode [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-store-json-object-in-cookie)

Comment: @Jagadesh raises more confusion. What is `grapObj` and `graphic`? Please post all the necessary code.

Comment: Consider grapobj is just string i am taking it as key where as **graphic** is a object

Comment: @Jagadesh can you [set up a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to replicate the problem?

Comment: It is very fuzzy thing i cant put all in fiddle. My requirement is i am placing a graphic feature in a map it wont be stored in server until i do some clicks meanwhile i am working on some other thing in that process if page is refreshed the graphics will be lost. My task is to store that in cookie and replace on the map.

Comment: @Jagadesh do a `console.log()` on the `json123` and `x`

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer yes i did json123 is giving as string '[object object] where as x is like json object {grap0:object}